# In attribute 'employees', the "mapped by" value 'project_id' cannot be resolved to an attribute on the target entity

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Hi there I am new to JPA and got following error as

`In attribute 'employees', the "mapped by" value 'project_id' cannot be resolved to an attribute on the target entity.`

with following code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    protected int id;

    @Column(name = "project_name")
    protected String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "project_id")
    protected List<Employee> employees;




@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    protected int id;

    @Column(name = "employee_name")
    protected String name;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Project.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "project_employee", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"))
    protected List<Project> projects;
```

Here If I am trying to map the inverse entity it says that attribute not found.

Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

As the message says your *mappedBy* value is wrong. It should be the name of the FIELD/PROPERTY on the other side of the BIDIRECTIONAL relation, that links back to this class. e.g `Project.employees` claims to link back via field `Employee.project_id`, yet that doesn't exist. Instead *mappedBy* should be `projects`. This would be found in any basic JPA docs